# Multiple "in" filters in Firestore query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a method that receives user input and then queries the Cloud Firestore database based on the selected filters. But to achieve the results that I need, I would have to perform a query with multiple "in" operators. Does someone have a workaround?
My method:

```js
      getGrouped: async function () {
        let array = [];
        const groupedQuery = query(
          collectionGroup(db, "grouped"),
          where("owner", "==", match.params.uid),
          where("capaign", "in", this.capaign),
          where("region", "in", this.region)
        );
        const groupedSnapshot = await getDocs(groupedQuery);
        groupedSnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
          array.push(doc.data());
        });
        return array;
      },
```

The user input looks like this: `["CA", "BO", "TX"]`

Comment: This is a documented limitation: **You can use at most one in, not-in, or array-contains-any clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query.**

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this result? The user input is an array of values that I want to use as a filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore only allows one `in` condition per query. You'll need to do the second one in JavaScript processing the results.

```
  getGrouped: async function () {
    let array = [];
    const groupedQuery = query(
      collectionGroup(db, "grouped"),
      where("owner", "==", match.params.uid),
      where("capaign", "in", this.capaign)
    );
    const groupedSnapshot = await getDocs(groupedQuery);
    groupedSnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
      if (this.region.includes(doc.get('region'))) {
        array.push(doc.data());
      }
    });
    return array;
  },
```

Comment: For the purposes of filtering results quickly, you might get a marginal boost from using `doc.get("region")` in the comparison and then `array.push(doc.data())` once you've confirmed that the doc is in the right region.

Comment: Like I said, I don't use Firebase. I was trying to find the syntax for reading a field in the documentation, couldn't, so I assumed it was normal property access. I've updated the answer.